# I need a Java method that returns a diamond pattern of numbers

Tags: java, methods

I am new to programming and decided to join an online Java course for beginners.

I am asked to do 2 things:

1. Print a sequence of digits with preceding and trailing white spaces on a single line. It is assumed that the method parameter centerDigit can only take values from 0 to 9. For example: printSequenceDigits( 2, 7 ) results in: " 01210 "
2. Print a diamond pattern of numbers on the terminal window, With the help of the printSequenceDigits() method. For example: printDigitDiamond(2) results in:

   > ```
   > "   0   "           
   > "  010  "         
   > " 01210 "        
   > "  010  "          
   > "   0   "
   > ```

So far I have been able to complete task 1, but I am unsure how I can implement the 2nd task using the "for" loop in the 1st task to display the diamond.

I would be grateful if anyone can get me on the way

Here is my code so far:

```
/**
 * Method which prints a sequence of digits with preceding and trailing white spaces on a single line 
 * of the terminal window.
 * 
 * @author  
 * @version 
 */
public class PrintSequenceDigits
{

    /**
     * Constructor which prints a sequence of digits with preceding and trailing white spaces on a single 
     * line of the terminal window
     */
    public static void printSequenceDigits(int centerDigit, int length) {
        // declare variables
        int integerCenterDigit, integerLength, integerStringLength, integerNetLength;
        String stringResults = "";
        // calculate length of stringResults
        integerStringLength = centerDigit * 2 + 1; // for printNumberLine( 2, 7 ) --> 2*2+1=5
        // calculate length of int length
        integerNetLength = (length - integerStringLength) / 2; // for printNumberLine( 2, 7 ) --> (7-5)/2=1
        for(integerCenterDigit = 0; 
            integerCenterDigit < integerNetLength; 
            integerCenterDigit++){
            stringResults = stringResults + ' '; // print blank space before
        }
        for(integerCenterDigit = 0; // print 0 
            integerCenterDigit <= centerDigit; // print 1 
            // print length +1 etc depending on input length
            integerCenterDigit++){
            stringResults = stringResults + integerCenterDigit; // for printNumberLine( 2, 7 ) print 012
        }
        for(integerCenterDigit = centerDigit -1; // print length -1 (=1)
            integerCenterDigit >= 0; 
            // print length -1 etc depending on input length
            integerCenterDigit--){
            stringResults = stringResults + integerCenterDigit; // for printNumberLine( 2, 7 ) print 10
        }
        for(integerCenterDigit = 0; 
            integerCenterDigit < integerNetLength; 
            integerCenterDigit++){ 
            stringResults = stringResults + ' '; // print blank space after
        }
        System.out.println(stringResults); // prints total of the above = " 01210 "
    }

    /**
     * Method which prints a diamond pattern of numbers on the terminal window 
     * 
     * @param
     * @return
     */
    public static void printDigitDiamond(int diamondCenter) {
        int integerDiamondCenter;

    }
}
```

Am I on the right track here or do I have to revise my for loop in task 1? 
Can this loop be constructed differently to make it easier to pass the results from task1 to task 2?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: look at the results from task1 and then answer your question :-)

Comment: Your second method doesn't yet exist, so one cannot say whether you are on track. If your first method _works_ then the task is trivial. All you need to work out is the **maximum** width (so for `printDigitDiamond(2)` would be  `5 + 2` (the output above seems to be padded in the middle). Then you loop from `0 -> centre -> 0` calling `printSequenceDigits(i, max)`. That's all.

Comment: You say you don't know how to "implement the 2nd task using the 'for' loop in the 1st task", but that's not your assignment or what you should do. If your first method is working, *don't touch it*. Rather, create a second method that **uses** (calls) your first method.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  Your first method does its task, right?  Check that off the list.  Now you need to print out a diamond digit using the first method, right?  You can accomplish two ways:

1. Let the first method do the printing.  Your 2nd task calls the first with the proper parameters to make the entire digit diamond be printed as you wish.
2. Remove "printing" from the equation by returning a String.

This 2nd solution is just as good as the first in your case, however in general the 2nd solution is better overall.  If you think about it, generating the string *AND* printing it are two separate tasks. You may not always want to do both, so logically you should separate them.

The actual printing is somewhat trivial, but if it weren't, then I would recommend creating a separate method to do that and if anything, create a method that calls both in order to both generate and print the string.  In this way you have full functionality and your code is not repeated.

In addition to this, there is a small optimization that I would recommend if you're having to append more than 3 Strings together.  There is a class called StringBuilder that has the silly task of optimizing construction of the string and that's all.

So that said, your method would become:

```java
public static void generateSequenceDigits(int centerDigit, int length) {
    int integerCenterDigit, integerLength, integerStringLength, integerNetLength;
    StringBuilder stringResults = new StringBuilder();

    integerStringLength = centerDigit * 2 + 1; 

    integerNetLength = (length - integerStringLength) / 2; 
    for(integerCenterDigit = 0; 
        integerCenterDigit < integerNetLength; 
        integerCenterDigit++){
        stringResults.append(' '); 
    }
    for(integerCenterDigit = 0;
        integerCenterDigit <= centerDigit; 
        // print length +1 etc depending on input length
        integerCenterDigit++){
        stringResults.append(integerCenterDigit);
    }
    for(integerCenterDigit = centerDigit -1; 
        integerCenterDigit >= 0; 

        integerCenterDigit--){
        stringResults.append(integerCenterDigit); 
    }
    // Not strictly necessary
    /*
    for(integerCenterDigit = 0; 
        integerCenterDigit < integerNetLength; 
        integerCenterDigit++){ 
        stringResults.append(' ');
    }
    */
    return stringResults.toString();  // <-- Build final string
}
```

Then to print it out, you'd do `System.out.println(generateSequenceDigits(2, 7));`.

In this way, you can reuse generateSequenceDigits in your 2nd method.  Like I did in the first, you could use StringBuilder to append lines and then return them in a gigantic String. In your main you would then simply print it out, though you could potentially write it to a file or save it to a database whereas if you simply printed it, you would have to first adapt your method.  I leave the other method to you to do.

PS - Also please note that the last loop appending spaces is not visible and so I commented it out.  There may be strange situations in which you may need it, so I would simply leave it commented out.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's "The Java Way" to do it for Boris...

**dtest.java**:

```
import edu.iastate.its.niads.demo.Diamond;

public class dtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Diamond d = new Diamond(4);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

**Diamond.java**:

```
package edu.iastate.its.niads.demo;
public class Diamond {
        private static final int DEF_SIZE = 4;
        private int size;

        public Diamond ( ) { this(DEF_SIZE); }
        public Diamond ( int size ) { setSize(size); }
        public void setSize ( int size ) { this.size = size; }
        public int getSize ( ) { return size; }

        @Override
        public int hashCode ( ) { return size; }

        @Override
        public boolean equals ( Object obj ) {
                if (!(obj instanceof Diamond)) return false;
                return (((Diamond)obj).size == this.size);
        }

        /* called printSequenceDigits() in the assignment */
        private String line ( int mx, int wid ) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(wid + 1);
                for (int s = 0; s < (wid/2) - mx; ++s) sb.append(' ');
                for (int u = 0; u < mx; ++u) sb.append(u);
                for (int d = mx; d >= 0; --d) sb.append(d);
                for (int s = 0; s < (wid/2) - mx; ++s) sb.append(' ');
                sb.append('\n');
                return sb.toString();
        }

        /* replaces printDigitDiamond() in the assignment */
        @Override
        public String toString () {
                int dim = (2 * size) + 3;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(dim * (dim+1));
                for (int u = 0; u < size; ++u) sb.append(line(u, dim));
                for (int d = size; d >= 0; --d) sb.append(line(d, dim));
                return sb.toString();
        }
}
```

**Sample run**:

> ```
> john% java dtest
>      0     
>     010    
>    01210   
>   0123210  
>  012343210 
>   0123210  
>    01210   
>     010    
>      0
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You are using too many loops in your solution. Your code is good as a beginner but if you want to explore more as you learn, here is a better implementation for `printDiamond()` and `printSequenceDigits()` functions.

I have also added comments to make you understand the program better. Feel free to comment if you want to understand any specif part.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    /* Print Diamond */
    printDiamond(4);
}

/**
 * Print Diamond
 * Arguments: Length of the diamond
**/
private static void printDiamond(int num) {
    /* Check Input Number */
    if(num < 0 || num > 9) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
        return;
    }

    /* Length = num*2 + 1 */
    for(int i = 0; i < num*2 + 1; i++) {
        /* Print Sequence Digits */
        printSequenceDigits(i <= num ? i : num*2 - i, num*2 + 1);
    }
}

/**
 * Print Sequence Digits
 * Arguments: Row Index, Total Length of Row
**/
private static void printSequenceDigits(int x, int length) {
    /* Crate Row Sequence */
    char[] ptr = new char[x*2+1];

    /* Fill The Values */
    for(int i = 0; i < ptr.length/2 + 1; i++) {
        /* First Half = Other Half (Reversed) */
        ptr[i] = ptr[ptr.length - 1 - i] = (char) (i + '0');
    }

    /* Pad Extra Spaces */
    char[] padding = new char[(length - ptr.length)/2];
    Arrays.fill(padding,' ');

    /* Print Sequence */
    System.out.println("\" " + new String(padding) + new String(ptr) 
                             + new String(padding) + " \"");
}
```

Output:

```
"     0     "
"    010    "
"   01210   "
"  0123210  "
" 012343210 "
"  0123210  "
"   01210   "
"    010    "
"     0     "
```

Comment: OP is trying to learn and as such, you're removing that experience from him by giving him the right answer. You didn't even explain *why* it is better.  If the objective of a good answer is to teach the OP something, then this is a terrible answer.

Comment: I clearly said that "Here is a better implementation". I'm not trying to take away his learning experiences but leaving him with other logic that he can implement. I have also provided comments to help him understand the program. What's wrong with it?

Comment: His words:  "Am I on the right track here or do I have to revise my for loop in task 1? Can this loop be constructed differently to make it easier to pass the results from task1 to task 2?"  Answer to question #1 if I had to guess is yes?  Maybe, if by revise you mean replace.  Answer to question #2 is yes?  Maybe, if by constructed differently you mean to replace.  If the question were "How can I do this?" this answer would be right on the money.

Comment: I don't like the solution at all. It's overly complex and smells like something a C programmer would write, in the "I can write C in any language" family of things.  Also, it does not help anyone, let alone the OP if you post fully baked solutions for cribbing.

Answer (score -3):

You can use below logic for print diamond.

```
    int  number = 3;
    int space = number -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {

        for(int s = 1; s <= space; s++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        space--;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        for (int p = i - 2 ; p >= 0; p--) {
            System.out.print(p);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    space = 0;
    for (int i = number; i > 0; i--) {

        for(int s = 0; s < space; s++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        space++;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        for (int p = i - 2 ; p >= 0; p--) {
            System.out.print(p);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Posting a full answer to a homework question if frowned upon.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: It means, the OP is trying to _learn_ as evidenced by their question "_[a]m I on the right track[?]_" You have posted a code dump. No explanation of _why_ it works. No explanation of _why_ it is better than the OP's solution. This does not help the OP learn.

Comment: ok... Thanks for the clarification & -1 Boris, will keep this mind from next time.

Comment: Furthermore, the OP was told to use their method from task (1). By not using that method, you are providing a *wrong* answer.

Comment: Remember though that these answers are not just for the OP, but also for everybody who finds this in the future...

Comment: Thanks guys, I will revise my for loops to make it easier to access the variables in the diamond part. Generally I have difficulty in using ++variable and variable++ as well as --variable and variable--. Just need to get my head around tham.

Comment: user2004685, the Arrays.fill(padding,' '); throws a compiler error as the array has not been initialized.

Comment: removing the /* Pad Extra Spaces */ code and adding String padding = " "; to the instance variables returns the correct result for printSequenceDigits, but it does not display the printDiamond correct. it displays the correct numbers with a blank space in front, but forms a triangle instead

Comment: @Guest `Arrays.fill(padding,' ');` throws a compiler error as the array has not been initialized. Are you sure that it has not been initialized? What do you think `char[] padding = new char[(length - ptr.length)/2];` is doing then? Just for your reference: http://ideone.com/O7FLot